# Checking whether the max and min values occur equally frequently

Tags: java, array

An array is defined to be "maxmin equal" if it contains at least two different elements and the number of times the maximum value occur is the same as the number of times the minimum value occur. So {11, 4, 9, 11, 8, 5 , 4, 10} is maxmin equal, because the max value 11 and min value 4 both appear two times in the array.

Write a function called `isMaxMinEqual` that accepts an integer array and returns 1 if the array is maxmin equal; otherwise it returns 0.

Note: Please do not use any string methods. No sorting allowed. No additional data structures including arrays allowed.

If the input array is:

{} | `isMaxMinEqual` should return 0 (array must have at least two different elements)

{2} | 0 (array must have at least two different elements)

{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} | 0 (array must have at least two different elements)

{2, 4, 6, 8, 11} | 1 (Both max value (11) and min value 2 appear exactly one time)

{-2, -4, -6, -8, -11} | 1 (Both max value (-2) and min value -11 appear exactly one time).

Here is my solution. Is it possible to combine the loops?

```
    int max;
    int min;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int minCount = 0;
    if (a.length > 2) {
        max = a[0];
        min = a[0];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int num : a) {
        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
        if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }
    }
    for (int num : a) {
        if (max == num) {
            maxCount++;
        }
        if (min == num) {
            minCount++;
        }
    }
    if (maxCount == minCount) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: You might be interested in this old question that solves the same problem: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117363/array-is-minmax-equal-or-not

Answer (score 4):

Reviews:

- Nomenclature "a" : Name doesn't reflect the motive.
- ">2" is incorrect. It should be ">1".
- `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}` will be incorrect in your case as min and max are same.
- `a` could be null so we should check

  ```
  if(input == null || input.size <2){
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Multiple returns, though debatable but advisable.
- Coming to reducing the loops:

  ```
  for (int num : a) {
      if (num > max) {
          max = num;
          maxCount = 1;
      } else if (num == max) {
          maxCount ++;
      }

      if (num < min) {
          min = num;
          minCount = 1;
      } else if (num == min) {
          minCount ++;
      }
  }
  ```
- If you wish to minimize further: `return (max != min && maxCount == minCount)`

Comment: Though I am tempted to give you +1 for mentioning the case of `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`, I am also tempted to give you a -1 because of the "Multiple returns" article.

Comment: My bad. I didn't check the heading of the article.

Comment: Personally I don't see anything bad with multiple returns at all.

Answer (score 2):

The key to only looping once is here:

```
for (int num : a) {
    if (num > max) {
        max = num;
    }
    if (num < min) {
        min = num;
    }
}
```

You can add a `if (num == max)` and `if (num == min)` and increase the `maxCount` and `minCount` there. And then you reset `maxCount` and `minCount` to 1 whenever you change the `max` or `min`.

```
for (int num : a) {
    if (num > max) {
        max = num;
        maxCount = 1;
    }
    if (num < min) {
        min = num;
        minCount = 1;
    }
    if (max == num) {
        maxCount++;
    }
    if (min == num) {
        minCount++;
    }
}
```

---

Other suggestions:

- Return a boolean `true`/`false` instead of an integer `1` and `0`.
- In the `if (a.length > 2)` check you will return the wrong result for an array such as [2, 10] which as far as I understand it correctly should return true.
- Use the name `input` instead of `a`.